# I need to take an inputted string, take the non-numeric characters out, and then if the string begins with a 1, remove the 1

Tags: javascript, regex, string, if-statement

```
function changeNumber(e) {
  var phoneNumber = e.replace(/\D/g, '');
  if (phoneNumber.startsWith("1")) {
    var finalNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0);
    return finalNumber;
  } else {
    return phoneNumber;
  };
};
console.log(changeNumber("+1 (234)-567.8995"));
```

Desired result should be: 2345678995 but I am getting 12345678995. It's like it's not running through the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a more concise function without conditionals

- `\D` matches all **non-digit** characters.
- `^1` matches 1 if it is the first character in the string.

```js
function changeNumber(e) {
  return e.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^1/g, '');
};
console.log(changeNumber("+1 (234)-567.8995"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) starting from index `1`, because you want to omit the first character at index `0`.

```
phoneNumber.slice(0)
```

returns a copy of the string, as an assignment of the variable, but

```
phoneNumber.slice(1)
```

returns the string from index 1 and all following characters.

```js
function changeNumber(e) {
    var phoneNumber = e.replace(/\D/g, '');
    return phoneNumber.startsWith("1")
        ? phoneNumber.slice(1)
        : phoneNumber;
}

console.log(changeNumber("+1 (234)-567.8995"));
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain why this is the case?